# Background check for proprietorship registration date vs employment date

Tags: recruitment, india

Six years ago, I worked in a sole proprietorship trading concern in customer service before entering into the IT industry.  I started working there in 2010, but that company was officially registered in 2011 (and still exists to this day).

In a background check, could it fail by asking why it's registered only in 2011 but you recorded your start date as 2010?

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting some of the grammatical issues in your question.  Please let me know if I have changed the original intent of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** It's possible.

Most organisations are most concerned about verifying the work you did, when and how well, not if the business you worked for was registered.  As long as you have references for your time from 2010, it's unlikely that someone will check business registration records.

Business registration is more of something that the tax department would care about.  *However*, understanding the need for relieving letters in India, perhaps sole trader registration is used to verify the term of your employment.  That is something you would probably need to talk to a legal expert in the field.

I *would* recommend that if the answer is "Yes, it is used to verify terms of employment" that you come clean immediately to any future employer about the discrepancy, or record your commencement date as a sole trader from the valid registration date.

Comment: What I'm missing here: this is why you should usually mention stuff like this when an employer is proceeding to background checks, just in case.

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, I can't disagree.  It was why I suggested talking to a lawyer who can give advice on what the impact on relieving letters, etc. would be.

Comment: Yeah good point, seems like I scanned over the Indian angle too quickly.